# How to get a list of packages not saved to package.json?

Tags: npm

I've installed a couple of packages here in my local machine, but I'm not able to know which ones I've installed.

Is there some framework to show me which packages and version are installed in my project (not-saved, saved and dev saved)?

I tried to compare the node_modules folders but the results are not very precise.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Just run `npm i`

Comment: I runned for example: `npm install bootstrap`, but I didn't put the --save. Now I want to know which lib I have installed and didn't put the --save/--save-dev.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is `npm list` (`npm ls` is handy alias).

Assuming you ran:

```
npm init
npm install -S postcss
npm install -D postcss-cli
npm install postcss-import
```

Then if you run `npm list --depth 0`, npm will print:

```
my-package@1.0.0 /home/.../my-package
├── postcss@5.2.16
├── postcss-cli@3.0.0-beta
└── postcss-import@9.1.0 extraneous

npm ERR! extraneous: postcss-import@9.1.0 /home/.../my-package/node_modules/postcss-import
```

All the packages marked with `extraneous` have been installed, but not added to `package.json`.

By default, `npm list` prints a full dependency graph. The `--depth` option limits the graph to the specified number of layers. `--depth 0` only prints the direct dependencies, not their dependencies, so that's what you want in this case.