# Create/update package.json for existing project

Tags: json, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I have a NodeJS project that was started long ago. It has *many* packages that were installed before I understood the --save flag. A few versions ago npm decided that it would delete packages that are not mentioned in package.json (an insane thing to do). This causes a terrible problem.

Now I understand --save and use it properly. However, I cannot figure out a way to update package.json with packages that are not listed.

Is there some way to cause npm or some other program to look at a project and add missing dependencies? I'd be happy enough if it completely recreated the dependency structure.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658010/how-to-get-a-list-of-packages-not-saved-to-package-json

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE : npm 3.5+**

Remove everything from package.json and run: `npm init --yes`.

This will recreate the package.json with dependencies, but not the devdependencies.

**npm 3**

If your're on Unix based systems, from inside your project root folder, with a package.json file already created (npm init, as you mentioned), run:

```
npm install $(ls node_modules/) --save
```

and it will reinstall the packages, and save them into package.json as dependencies

Comment: Will that necessarily install the same versions? (I'm not sure whether npm will pick up the existing versions or not)

Comment: This suggestion works but isn't sufficient. 
It will get the links from the current directory. It will not update the entire project. If you miss a directory, npm will often delete components that are not in a package.json.